# sending tezos from texbox/ operation failed hardware device error

Tags: tezos-client

Attempted several times to send tokens from tezbox wallet to another wallet. Got the error message: operation failed / hardware device failed... I am using laptop without connecting to any hardware device. 
I increased the fee/gas and the wallet address is correct I'm sending to. 
I downloaded tezbox maybe 7 weeks ago so it should be current. 
Why can't I send my tezos? Pls?

Comment: The Tezos stackexchange is not for Tezbox support. If you have a very specific question related to Tezos please ask one and it will likely get an answer. For Tezbox support either use twitter or go to their telegram t.me/TezTechLabs